# IPhone development on a hacked IPhone

Tags: iphone

You knows that IPhone in other country like China mainland always be hacked when it buy from reseller. Can I develop custom app by official SDK on a hacked IPhone ?

Comment: Or use some ways to refresh the IPhone's OS to official OS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Xcode to develop and debug your app on a jailbroken iPhone. You don't even need to pay the $99 to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your iPhone is running firmware 2.0 or higher, you can use the official SDK to develop your applications and use the *ldid* tool to fake the code signature process. Then, your iPhone will be able to run the application just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the SDK from the Apple site, this does require using a Mac though.
You could use a Hackintosh or VMWare, but this isn't entirely legal.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming advice, not legal advice.  I personally believe this is not the place for legal advice

Comment: No, but I thought it'd be best to include the fact that a particular way to solve a problem might be illegal.
It's not exactly nice to tell someone to do something without telling them that it might have consequences.